# Magento 2.x - Menu not showing for custom role in custom module

Tags: magento2, module, magento-2.1, extensions

I am working Magento 2.x custom module. I have setup ACL rules for this but it is not showing Menu of custom module for custom user roles.

> acl.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Acl/etc/acl.xsd">
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <resource id="Magento_Backend::admin">
                <resource id="technologymindz::base" title="TM Tag Manager" sortOrder="10" >
                    <resource id="technologymindz_googletagmanager::googletagmanager" title="General Settings" sortOrder="10" />
                </resource>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </acl>
</config>
```

> menu.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../Backend/etc/menu.xsd">
    <menu>
        <add id="technologymindz::base" title="TM Tag Manager" module="Technologymindz_GoogleTagManager" sortOrder="10" resource="Technologymindz_GoogleTagManager::sample"/>

        <add id="technologymindz_googletagmanager::googletagmanager" title="General Settings" module="Technologymindz_GoogleTagManager" sortOrder="10" parent="technologymindz::base" action="technologymindz_googletagmanager/items/" resource="Technologymindz_GoogleTagManager::items"/>
    </menu>
</config>
```

custom module menu listing in resource list and setting is saved.
[image]

But when login and check for custom user role, it is not showing.
[image]

> Index Controller is using permission

```
protected function _isAllowed()
{
 return $this->_authorization->isAllowed('technologymindz::base');
}
```

I have used `static content deploy` and `cache flush`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your acl code as below

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Acl/etc/acl.xsd">
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <resource id="Magento_Backend::admin">
                <resource id="Technologymindz_GoogleTagManager::sample" title="TM Tag Manager" sortOrder="10" >
                    <resource id="Technologymindz_GoogleTagManager::items" title="General Settings" sortOrder="10" />
                </resource>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </acl>
</config>
```

Comment: Its works for me

Answer (score 2):

If your resource name is `Technologymindz_GoogleTagManager::items` then you need to check same in your `_isAllowed()` method

```
protected function _isAllowed()
{
    return $this->_authorization->isAllowed('Technologymindz_GoogleTagManager::items');
}
```

Edit:
I also recommend to set id and resource attributes in menu.xml with same values `Technologymindz_GoogleTagManager::items`

Answer (score 1):

The `resource` attribute on the menu items must match the `id` attribute from the resource tag in `acl.xml`

Your resource ids are `technologymindz::base` and `technologymindz_googletagmanager::googletagmanager` in `acl.xml` but your in the menu file you are using `technologymindz_googletagmanager::googletagmanager` and `Technologymindz_GoogleTagManager::items`.
Chance the ones in `menu.xml` to match the ones in `acl.xml`.  Also make sure you match the case sensitivity.

Comment: As per your suggestion i have updated my `acl.xml` but still not working. `
            <resource id="Magento_Backend::admin">
     <resource id="technologymindz_googletagmanager::googletagmanager" title="TM Tag Manager" sortOrder="10" >
      <resource id="Technologymindz_GoogleTagManager::items" title="General Settings" sortOrder="10" />
                </resource>
            `

Comment: if this is wrong, can you update answer for `acl.xml` ?

Comment: if you updated acl.xml you need to create your role again. because the old item values are stored in the database.